# Passing a time_t array as a function parameter

Tags: array, functions

I'm trying to log reconnections and disconnections of a network. For that I've created 2 `time_t` arrays to store such occurances:

```
const int logSize = 10;
time_t conLog[logSize];
time_t disconLog[logSize];
```

Now, down the road, I have some manipulation and time calculation to do, and for that I wish to pass those log as a variable.

For example - zeroing its values:

```
void initLog(time_t log[], time_t init_val = 0)
{
        int sizeLog = sizeof(log) / sizeof(log[0]);
        Serial.print("size: ");
        Serial.println(sizeLog);
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeLog; i++)
        {
                log[i] = init_val;
        }
}
```

in order using it in a simple way : `initLog(conLog);`
But unfortunately this is wrong.

I've tried to replace `time_t log[]` with `time_t &log` - but still no luck.

What do I do wrong ?

Comment: you must pass the size as an additional parameter. the size of the array entering the function is unknown at runtime

Comment: @Juraj - Meaning that it is ref OK but its size can't be calculated ?

Comment: pointer or reference is the beginning address only

Comment: @Juraj that I know....

Comment: so how would the size be calculated? there is no information about the end address or length. the way you calculate the size works for a specific array when the compiler knows the definition of the array. but array of any length can be passed to this function

Comment: @Juraj well I thought there is some kind of a null termination sign. It works - thank you!

Comment: for char array that is a convention. for array of pointers you could use a null pointer as mark. here you could choose some time_t value as end mark, but generally all have a meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass an array to a function it "collapses" the array into just a pointer. All the receiving function knows is the type of the contents of the array (`time_t`) and where it starts in memory - it knows nothing about the size of the array.

The `sizeof()` call just gives you the size of that pointer, not the size of the memory it points to.

`sizeof()` is not actually a function, it's a compile-time construct. It can't know anything about runtime values, only what is there at compile time.

Instead you must pass the length of the array with the array as a separate parameter, which can only be calculated in the same scope as where the array is defined, and then only by using the original name of the array.  It is typical to create a macro to do this for you at the time you make the array:

```
time_t conLog[logSize];
#define CONLOG_SIZE (sizeof(conLog) / sizeof(conLog[0]))
```

Then pass that to your function:

```
initLog(conLog, CONLOG_SIZE);
```

Alternatively, since you already have the size in a constant in this case, you could just use that:

```
initLog(conLog, logSize);
```

Comment: Good answer, except... If you have a constant `logSize` that you use to create conLog, why write code to calculate it? Just use `logSize` directly.

Comment: @DuncanC In this instance that is true, but it is seldom the case.

Comment: Why? For arrays who's size is defined at compile time, using a compile-time constant to express that size is a good, clean way to do it.

Comment: @DuncanC Yes. You know that. I know that. Very few Arduino users know that. You have to remember: these are Arduino users, **not programmers**.

Comment: Some of us are both...

Comment: But most aren't. That is why you answer questions and don't ask questions. Just remember to tailor your answers to the level of the audience. If in doubt read up on Wittgenstein's ladder, and "lies to children".

Comment: I like your edit, proposing the best option. Why are people downvoting this answer? It is the **correct** answer.

Comment: ...Jealousy...?